# JAVA : Need help reading from a data file

Tags: java

I am reading from an text file Book.txt, and trying to create a Book object constructed as follows:

```
public Book(Person author, String title, String isbn, int year, BookGenre genre){
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.year = year;
        this.genre = genre;
    }
```

Here is what a sample of the input file looks like:

```
   Stieg Larsson 0 "The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo" 0307269752 2001 mystery
    Brandon Stanton 0 "Humans of New York" 1250038820 2013 travel
    Oscar Wilde 0 "The Importance of Being Earnest" 158049580X 1895  comic
    Douglas Hofstadter 0 "Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid" 0465026567 1979 science
```

I am not exactly sure what use the 0's could provide that are located after the author's name, so I will probably just delete them, unless you guys have any idea as to how they could be used.

Here is the code I am using to read in the file:

```
else if(name.equals("Book.txt")){
        ArrayList<Book> p = new ArrayList<Book>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Book.txt"));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
            String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
            p.add(new Book(new Person(tokens[0], tokens[1], Integer.parseInt(tokens[2])), tokens[3], tokens[4], Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]), tokens[6]));
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        }
```

I am getting an error which says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "with"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:59)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:460)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:510)
        at SortingImplementation.main(SortingImplementation.java:43)
```

So I am pretty sure I am simply reading the file wrong. Does anyone see anything that can be changed to make it work better?

Comment: You're splitting on spaces. The character between "Girl" and "with" is also a space. But your code is somehow assuming it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see how your code compiles in the first place since you're expecting a `BookGenre` as the last parameter for your `Book` constructor and you're passing a `String` to it. But since that's not the issue described, let's just assume `BookGenre` class has a simple constructor taking in a `String` to fix things and you're actually calling that in the end.

Nevertheless, like BalusC pointed out, your problem is that you're expecting title to be just one word, which it in your example data is not.

If you really want to do this by splitting text by the word and parsing them, then follow up with this sort of logic (no, it's not a full solution as that'd require lots more lines, but should have enough hints there for you to figure out the rest):

```
private Book parseBookFromLine(String line) throws Exception {
  String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
  Person author = new Person(tokens[0], tokens[1], Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]));
  String title = "";
  int nextToken = 3;

  /*
   * Assume next token starts with quotation marks or throw an exception about
   * malformed data.
   */

  if (tokens[nextToken].endsWith("\"")) {
    // Skim away the quotation.
    String temp = tokens[nextToken++];
    title = temp.substring(1, temp.length - 1);
  } else {
    /*
     * Loop and keep updating the title until you find next token with 
     * quotation mark or there are only five tokens left. In the latter case,
     * if no quotation marks found at the end of current token, throw exception
     * again about malformed data.
     */
  }

  return new Book(author, title, tokens[nextToken++],
                  Integer.parseInt(tokens[nextToken++]),
                  new BookGenre(tokens[nextToken++])));
}
```